# Design and Fill printable documents in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, document

I am trying to find software that will allow me to design a printable document. However, this printable document must be filled dynamically in a C# application.

Some things to note, this process should happen entirely in the background without user intervention. Once they submit on a website, the backing service will pull data from the DB, Fill out an object, and then should be able to generate a document that can be printed and stored (pdf/word/etc...).

The current possible solution is Aspose.Words, which does a great job for allowing me to fill in the data dynamically. However, it doesn't allow a lot of flexibility in design. The template designs in word aren't easy to work with and creating programatically doesn't look very appealing when printed.

I have also started to look at Ironpdf as we could just design HTML/CSS/Javascript and then convert to PDF. However, I don't see how that contains variables I can fill dynamically through our application.

I want to make sure we can design a document/report that looks very nice, can be stored and printed for use later, and can be filled with data from the DB whenever an API endpoint is called.

Thank you for any recommendations/suggestions and I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: There are a *lot* of reporting libraries. You can use the built-in PrintDocument too. If you want software recommendations use softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: "Reporting" involves selecting, ordering, grouping, summarizing .... and reporting. I think you've underestimated what constitutes "reporting", and what "report writers" can or cannot do.